# Attached in/on this email

Tags: prepositions

I'm writing an email, and I've the following doubt: To say that I'm sending a file alongside the email itself (there is a file attached to the email) is correct to say "I'm sending the document attached on this email" or "I'm sending the document attached in this email"?

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange question because you used the correct preposition in the question itself, namely "to."

In English as well as in the four European languages that I am acquainted with, which prepositions go with which verbs is not subject to rule, but is simply a matter of common usage.

In the case of "attached," the usage is clearcut.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attached+on%2Cattached+to%2C+attached+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattached%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattached%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattached%20in%3B%2Cc0

Comment: So, the right way to use that sentence is "I'm sending the document attached to this email"?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Why would you think otherwise? It was the preposition that you came up with when you were not obsessing about it.